# SpressenseのArduinoIDEでのシリアル通信バッファサイズは変更可能か？

Tags: spresense

SpressenseのArduinoIDE利用でのシリアル通信時のバッファサイズはArduinoと同じく64Byteなのでしょうか？
また、バッファサイズについて変更可能でしょうか。
大き目のデータのやり取りがしたく、溢れないようにバッファサイズを256Byteに拡張したいと考えています。

通常のArduinoのボードでの設定は下記の記事の通り変更出来るようなのですが、

[arduinoのbufferを64byteから256byteに増やす](https://qiita.com/showmeear/items/5d37e717b03a14dc74d8)

Spressenseの以下の場所にある同様のファイルを確認してもバッファサイズの記載がありませんでした。

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SPRESENSE\hardware\spresense\2.3.0\cores\spresense
```

バッファサイズや変更の可否についてご教授いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ちなみにサイズの単位は`KB`ではなく`K`の付かない`バイト`だと思われます。版数は違いますがこの辺を見ると、何の機能/ライブラリを使うかで変わってきそうですが。[Search - BUFFER](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/search?p=2&q=BUFFER), [Search - RX](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/search?p=1&q=RX)

Comment: サイズ単位記載ミスでした。ご指摘ありがとうございます。
修正しておきました。拡張ボードのSerial2での受信バッファ部分が変更できると良いのですが、Serial2の記載があるHardwareSerial.cppにはバッファ関連の記載がなさそうでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpresenseのSerial2のバッファサイズは既に256byteになっているようです。

バッファサイズをそれ以上に大きくしたい場合、Spresense SDK側のコンフィグレーションを変更してArduino用パッケージを作り直せば対応できると思います。

- 受信バッファ: CONFIG_UART2_RXBUFSIZE
- 送信バッファ: CONFIG_UART2_TXBUFSIZE

Arduino用パッケージの作り方はマニュアルを参考にしてください。
[Spresense Arduino board package パッケージのローカルインストール](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_spresense_arduino_board_package_%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

[Spresense SDKのコンフィグレーションを変更する場合](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_spresense_sdk%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88)の方法で、`menuconfig` を開いて、`Receive buffer size` や `Transmit buffer size`を256から変更してみてください。

```
 -> Device Drivers
   -> Serial Driver Support
     -> UART2 Configuration
       (256) Receive buffer size
       (256) Transmit buffer size
```

あとは手順通りにビルドしてローカルパッケージを作成して、そのパッケージをインストールすればバッファサイズを拡張できるようになると思います。

私はマニュアルをみながらパッケージを作成できましたが、少々難易度が高めです。それと開発環境はLinuxかMac環境を使うことをオススメします。Windowsだと処理が遅すぎてパッケージ作成にかなり時間がかかってしまいます（自分がハマったので）。参考まで。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます！非常に助かりました。
既に256byteになっているとのことで、まずはこのまま実装進めてみたいと思います。
それでも溢れるようならご教授いただいた方法を試してみたいと思います。